# offsetByCodePoints vs integer iterator

Tags: java, string

Is there any advantage to using String.offsetByCodePoints instead of just using an integer index to keep track of where you are in a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be useful if the string contains characters from the Unicode Supplementary Planes (unusual characters with a high code point / character code). Java strings use UTF-16 encoding internally, which means that some Unicode characters must be represented as a sequence of two `char` values, also known as a *surrogate pair*. Thus, although `s.charAt(i)` will give you the *i*'th `char` of `s`, this might not actually be the *i*'th *character*. `s.offsetByCodePoints(0, i)` will tell you the index where the *i*'th character starts.

If you are unfamiliar with some of the terms above, you should read [Joel Spolsky's excellent article on character sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: Thanks for the great article! When using UTF-8 is it ever possible to have a surrogate pair?

Comment: @erin: Not per se, since UTF-8 is structured differently - however, with UTF-8, most non-English characters (even not-too-exotic ones, such as the first character in the Norwegian spelling of my first name: Åsmund) will be represented as sequences of two, three or more bytes (whereas English characters take only one byte). However, Java strings are never encoded in UTF-8, so there are no methods on `String` to handle such byte sequences.

Comment: @erin: Note, though, that if your program opens a file and reads it, the program must handle the fact that the _file_ may have another encoding than UTF-16. The file encoding is typically specified when creating some kind of reader object. While reading `String` data from the file, Java will take care of conversion from the file encoding to UTF-16. `a` (which takes one byte in UTF-8) will become one `char`, `Å` (which takes two bytes in UTF-8) will also become one `char`, while some other obscure character (that takes several bytes in UTF-8) would become two `char`s.